# C++ Code Reuse between Failed Construction and Destruction

Tags: c++

I have a class that wraps some unmanaged resources. They are allocated in the constructor and freed in the destructor according to the RAII pattern. The allocation is not atomic, however, and, should a late stage of the constructor fail, it is necessary to free all the resources allocated in earlier stages before throwing an exception to the caller.

More and more, this edge-case code is beginning to resemble the destructor itself.

I know that a C++ class is capable of calling its own destructor and, because the destructor is implemented to handle instances that are left in a zombie state by a move operation, the destructor already checks to see if resources were actually allocated before attempting to free them. So, is it acceptible for a class to call its destructor in the event that construction fails?

The alternative is to create a named method called `release()` or `uninitialise()` or something similar and call that method in the event that construction fails and as the main body of the destructor.

Which is the better pattern?

Comment: Use RAII all the way.

Comment: One word: Single responsibility.

Comment: There is no way to break the class up into more granular classes, each implementing RAII, so as to satisfy "single responsibility". The problem tends to arise in copy constructors and other fancy constructors - while the most simple constructor is essentially atomic, these more complicated ones have nearly always two phases: one, which initialises the unmanaged resource much like the most simple constructor, and one which copies data to it or configures it in some non-atomic and non-guaranteed way that might fail. Since this is working with a legacy API that is NOT RAII.

Answer (score 5):

A better - than either of your suggestions - pattern would be to use RAII for each member object as well, rather than merely for the composite object.

Adhere to the single responsibility principle. One object should only ever manage the memory of a single object or a single array.

A composite object such as yours should have as members only these RAII objects that handle their own memory. If construction of one member succeeds and another throws, then the destructor of first member will be called and it will free it's own memory.

There is `std::unique_ptr` in the standard library for this type of ownership.

Answer (score 2):

As well as implmenting RAII yourself you should also use constructs that implement RAII.

So instead of doing something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
        : buffer_(new char[512])
        , resource_(new Resource)
    {
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete resource_;
        delete[] buffer_;
    }

private:
    char* buffer_;
    Resource* resource_;
};
```

You do this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
        : buffer_(512, 0)
        , resource_(new Resource)
    {
    }

private:
    // std::vector and std::unique_ptr will free up any resources they 
    // acquire in their destructors so I don't have to do anything explicit in mine
    std::vector<char> buffer_;
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> resource_;
};
```

This way if anything fails in your constructor and you throw for example you can be sure that all prior resources that have already been acquired will be released.